# How to pattern match on List('(', List[Char],')')?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am struggling a bit with some pattern matching on a List[Char]. I would like to extract sub-lists that are enclosed by parentheses. So, I would like to extract "test" as a List[Char] when given "(test)". So basically a match on List('(', List[Char],')'). I am able to match on List('(',t,')') where t is a single character, but not a variable amount of characters.

How should this be declared?

```
val s = "(test)" 
s match {
    case List('(',t,')') => {
        println("matches single character")
    }
    case '('::x::y => {
       //x will be the first character in the List[Char] (after the '(') and y the tail  
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is going to be possible without defining your own extractor, using a regex extractor, etc.

Comment: Like Travis, I would go for a regex expression.

Comment: @TravisBrown `+:` and `:+` extractors are enough and they are already defined in the standard library.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Ah, right. That's what I get for commenting too early in the morning. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s match {
  case '(' +: t :+ ')' => ...
}
```

Read about custom extractors in Scala and then see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.$colon$plus$ to understand how it works.

Note that it'll match any suitable `Seq[Char]`, but a string isn't really one; it can only be converted (implicitly or explicitly). So you can use one of

```
val s: Seq[Char] = ...some String or List[Char]
val s = someString.toSeq
```

I expect that performance for String should be good enough (and if it's critical, don't use this); but for large `List[Char]` this will be quite slow.

Comment: I see that :+/+: are extractors used to head/tail deconstruct sequences.  Now it is possible to extend it with Char +: '(' +: middle :+ ')' as well. I hoped it would be possible to chain even more on this like List[Char] +: '(' +: middle :+ ')'. Do you know a way to extend the matching?

Comment: `:+` and `+:` allow you to split only one element off, so it won't work for that case (you could write `_ +: '(' +: middle :+ ')'`, but it would only handle the case where you have 1 character before `(`. And you can't have a `++` extractor: in `List(0,1,2,3) match { case s1 ++ s2 => ... }`, how would you decide which part is `s1` and which is `s2`?

Comment: But you can match it by a regular expression, and as Travis Brown mentions, you can use regexes as extractors. This will only work if you have a `String`, not a `List` or other `Seq`, though.